# Codecademy Python 2 Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: python, string, list, int

I am just starting coding, growing like a baby each day

It gets tough but reviewing my notes and trying to understand/ memorize code.

Please explain for me what to do for this code.

```
from random import randint
"""This program will enable the user and computer to start a rock paper scissors game"""

options = ["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"]

message = {"tie": "Yawn it's a tie!", "won": "Yay you won!", "lost": "Aww you lost!"}


def decide_winner(user_choice, computer_choice):
    print("You chose %s") % (user_choice)

    print("PC chose %s") % (computer_choice)

    if user_choice == computer_choice:
        print(message["tie"])  # tie

    # user - paper , pc = rock
    elif user_choice == options[1] and computer_choice == options[0]:
        print(message["won"])

    # user - scissor , pc = paper
    elif user_choice == options[2] and computer_choice == options[1]:
        print(message["won"])

    # user - rock , pc - scissors
    elif user_choice == options[0] and computer_choice == options[1]:
        print(message["won"])

    else:
        print("YOU LOSE!")


def play_RPS():
    user_choice = input("Enter Rock, Paper, Scissors: ")

    computer_choice = options[randint(0,2)]
    decide_winner(user_choice, computer_choice)

play_RPS()
```

Comment: Please tell what you understand so far.

Answer (score 0):

A couple notes - `elif user_choice == options[0] and computer_choice == options[1]:` should be `elif user_choice == options[0] and computer_choice == options[2]:` Your comments were right but you indexed '1' instead of '2' for SCISSORS.

Python is case sensitive, so 'ROCK' will not equal 'Rock'. You need to possibly add the line

`user_choice = user_choice.upper()` in the function `def play_RPS():` before passing it to

`decide_winner(user_choice, computer_choice)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Python 2 uses input for things like variables and raw_input for things like strings.

Instead of:

```py
user_choice = input("Enter Rock, Paper, Scissors: ")
```

Use

```py
user_choice = raw_input("Enter Rock, Paper, Scissors: ")
```

2. Inputs are case sensitive
   Your options are

```
options = ["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"]
```

But if a person types "Rock" it shows that they lose
Instead change

```
user_choice = raw_input("Enter Rock, Paper, Scissors: ")
```

To

```
user_choice = raw_input("Enter Rock, Paper, Scissors: ").upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

from random import randint

"""This program will enable the user and computer to start a rock paper scissors game"""

options = ["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"]

message = {"tie": "Yawn it's a tie!", "won": "Yay you won!", "lost": "Aww you lost!"}

best_of_three = 3

def decide_winner(user_choice, computer_choice):

```
    print('You chose %s' % user_choice)

    print("PC chose %s" % computer_choice)

    if user_choice == computer_choice:

        print(message["tie"])  # tie

# user - paper , pc = rock
    elif user_choice == options[1] and computer_choice == options[0]:
        print(message["won"])
# user - scissor , pc = paper
    elif user_choice == options[2] and computer_choice == options[1]:
        print(message["won"])
        # user - rock , pc - scissors
    elif user_choice == options[0] and computer_choice == options[1]:
        print(message["won"])
    else:
        print("YOU LOSE!")
```

def play_RPS():

```
user_choice = input("Enter Rock, Paper, Scissors: ").upper()

computer_choice = options[randint(0, 2)]

decide_winner(user_choice, computer_choice)
```

play_RPS()